# Jersey not able to map json request to class

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I m able to run Jersey with Json output and able to get "GET" requests with JSon mapping without any problems.

I was also having some JSON methods which were "POST" methods and they are mapping to Java classes like in this method -

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/post")
public String postPerson(Person pers)
```

For your reference I m following the guide [here](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson) or [here](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

On giving a valid post request on these, they all started to throw the below error -

My maven dependencies, pom.xml is file at the end of the question -

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
newa.PersonResource.postPerson(PersonResource.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

The Person class -

```
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Person {    
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
}
```

The data I m sending using postman(Chrome extension) is in like -

[image: screenshot]

My pom.xml file -

```
 <dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What is at line 31 of PersonResource?

Comment: its pers.getFirstName() where pers is the Person object received from the method parameter (public String postPerson(Person pers) )

Comment: What is the json payload that you are sending over and what does the Person object look like?

Comment: @Derek_M i have edited my question with the Person class and the Postman request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the postman screenshot, it looks like you are sending over form-data, when you are actually wanting json (unless this is a new way you can input post data into POSTMAN. I just tried and could only input form-data this way).

Go to postman, click on the `body` tab, click the `raw` radio button, then choose `application/json` from the dropdown menu on the right. From there, input your body as json, which would look something like:

```
{"firstName": "Bill", "lastName": "Loney"}
```

Comment: i am getting same error but i am sending get request