# Migrate Jersey project to use Java 10 results in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, java-10, tomcat9

Previously, when the project was on Tomcat 8 and Java 8, it was working fine, but after I migrated my project to Tomcat 9 and Java 10, it is giving me error as follows:

```
Oct 05, 2018 11:02:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:915)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:869)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:775)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1206)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1174)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

My pom.xml file is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.BAE</groupId>
  <artifactId>BAE</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>BAE Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org./mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.14.3</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.interceptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-interceptor-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/jackson-xml-databind -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-models -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.20</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m05</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse/yasson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>BAE_4_4</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
          <exclude>main/**</exclude>
          <exclude>test/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
            
          <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/BAE</path>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Above are all dependencies jar files which I used in Tomcat 8 and Java 8.

Can anyone suggest me what is the cause and solution for this issue?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>`...looks like an older version of `asm` which doesn't support JDK10.

Comment: should i update asm jar file

Comment: so big file. I am using jackson, jersey jar files

Comment: try explicitly specifying `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>` to override the existing version once, if that might help.. ideally jersey might already be working on upgrading the same as well.

Comment: @nullpointer i tried but same issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### tl;dr

To use Java 10, switch to Jersey 2.27 (which is the latest as of this date (10/5/18)).

---

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>
```

Jersey repackages asm and puts these class files into the `jersey-server` jar. Just digging through the jar in my IDE, I looked at the `ClassReader` constructor (that's what `<init>` means) to see where IllegalArgumentException is thrown. Note, I'm currently looking at Jersey version 2.25.1

```java
public ClassReader(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
    this.b = b;
    if (this.readShort(off + 6) > 53) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

The 53 is the [class file version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9170832/2587435). According to that link, 53 is for Java 9. So it appears Jersey 2.25.1 only supports up to Java 9. So I changed the Jersey dependency version to 2.26, and looked at the `ClassReader` constructor and it was exactly the same. So I switched to Jersey 2.27, and this is what I saw

```java
public ClassReader(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
    this.b = b;
    // checks the class version
    // added "support" for java 11 compiled classes
    if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V11) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Notice the `Opcodes.V11` (which I assume is Java 11). So it looks like for Java 10+ support, you must switch to Jersey 2.27, as also mentioned in [this related issue](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3799)

---

### Update

After seeing your pom, you need to make sure you are changing the Jersey version on all your Jersey dependencies. And also you have so many unnecessary dependencies. The following are all you need. Remove anything else that has Jersey in the name.

**KEEP THESE**

Change to 2.27

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

**REMOVE THESE**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m05</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**ADD EXCLUSION**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

---

### Asides

- See the Jersey [Migration Guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-2.27) for some other issues you may face when migrating to version 2.27

  The one for sure thing you will need if you are migrating from pre-2.26 is the `jersey-hk2` dependency. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217530/2587435) for why.

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>2.27</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)

Comment: It's impossible to say what that is without more information.

Comment: Is that the root cause? I googled that error, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40662549/2587435), which suggests it is not the root cause. If there is a root cause, that's what we need to know.

Comment: after adding still i am getting same error which i mentioned in question

Comment: After adding what? I am not suggesting that your error is the same as the linked problem. I am saying that the error you posted in the comment is not the root cause and I need to know the root cause to help you.

Comment: no no means after adding jersey 2.27 version jar files

Comment: Yes but you posted another error in the comment. That is not the whole stack trace. Please update you original question with the entire stack trace.

Comment: i posted my pom .xml file

Comment: one more question this latest versions of jersey can work on tomcat 8 and jdk 8 ?

Comment: Jersey Migration Guide is now at https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html