# Jersey 1.19.4 on Java 11

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jax-ws, java-11

Can Jersey 1.19.4 work on Java 11?

If not, Is there an equivalent to Jersey 1.19.4 that support the same api and still works on Java 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should upgrade to [version 2.29](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e559) (at least)

> Since Jersey 2.29, all modules can be built using Java SE 11 and all distributed modules provide support for Java SE 8+ (9,11).

For Java 10 use at least [2.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658991/migrate-jersey-project-to-use-java-10-results-in-java-lang-illegalargumentexcept)

> See the Jersey Migration Guide for some other issues you may face when migrating to
> version 2.27

Comment: I am required to maintain compatibility on Java 8 and Java 11 for the time being. Would Jersey v2.28 be suitable for that?

Comment: Use 2.29v because it was tested on it https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/pull/4067

Comment: Please use the latest Jersey 2.x. Jersey 2.x remains compatible with JDK 8.