# Using Java1.8, JSF 8.0, wildfly 13 and maven 3.3.3. Issue is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader

Tags: jboss, jersey, wildfly

We are working on jar updates and removing unwanted jars from the project. As you can see it's a very old project and many have added unwanted jars based on their requirment.
I am getting below error from past week, even if I revert my code to past production code. I have removed below jars from the project as we are having SCA scan errors on these. There are no compile issue but getting below exception on runtime.
from WEB-INF/lib
jackcess-1.2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
gson-1.6.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
below from a folder, not used in the project.
jsp-api-2.1-6.0.0.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
json-20090211.jar
servlet-2.3.jar

Help would be much appreciated...

```
    07:50:24,097 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Running on PrimeFaces 8.0
    07:50:24,167 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
      /WEB-INF/lib
      /WEB-INF/classes
    07:50:24,842 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CactusServer: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CactusServer: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:300)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:140)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:584)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:555)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:597)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        ... 8 more
    
    07:50:24,868 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "CactusServer.war")]) - failure description: {
        "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CactusServer" => "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"},
        "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
            "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"CactusServer.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
            "Services that may be the cause:" => [
                "jboss.clustering.web.route.default-server",
                "jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa",
                "jboss.txn.service.remote",
                "jboss.xts.handlers",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.ejb",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.web",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.ejb.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.default-server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.ejb.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.ejb.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.default-server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.ejb.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.default-server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.default-server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.ejb",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.hibernate",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.local",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.web",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.default-command-dispatcher-factory",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.group.hibernate",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.group.server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.group.web",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.default-server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.expiration",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.locking",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.memory",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.transaction",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.expiration",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.locking",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.memory",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.transaction",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.expiration",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.locking",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.memory",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.transaction",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.expiration",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.locking",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.memory",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.transaction",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.client-mappings",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.default-server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.expiration",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.locking",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.memory",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.transaction",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.write",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.hibernate",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.web",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate.transport",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server.transport",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web.transport",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.ejb",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.web",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.server",
                "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.web"
            ]
        }
    }

**POM file**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>CactusServer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Cactus Server Project</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xorail</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xorail.talon.pom</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../com.xorail.talon.pom</relativePath>
        <version>${app-version}</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Jboss 3rd party</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xorail</groupId>
            <artifactId>CactusShared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xorail</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.xorail.util.property</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xorail</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.xorail.qaqc</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.framework/richfaces-api 
            <dependency> <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId> <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId> 
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.framework/richfaces-impl 
            <dependency> <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId> <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId> 
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.framework/richfaces-impl-jsf2 
            <dependency> <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId> <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId> 
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.ui/richfaces-ui <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId> <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId> 
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cron-utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cronutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>cron-utils</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.dozer/dozer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.faces/jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk/tomahawk21 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk21</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId> <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.15</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redmine related references -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.taskadapter/redmine-java-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.taskadapter</groupId>
            <artifactId>redmine-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.themes/casablanca -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>5.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52658991/2587435

Comment: How did you install Jersey into WildFly?

Comment: Could JDK version be an issue? ASM 3.2 from your pom did not support JDK 8, and Jersey  1 repackaged ASM 5 supporting JDK 8 only around version 1.19