# Migrate Jersey project to use Java 17 results in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-8, jersey, java-17

I am migrating my maven based java project from jdk8 to jdk17. Now I am facing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:171)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.ScanningHibernateBundle.findEntityClassesFromDirectory(ScanningHibernateBundle.java:48)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.ScanningHibernateBundle.<init>(ScanningHibernateBundle.java:30)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.ScanningHibernateBundle.<init>(ScanningHibernateBundle.java:26)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.ScanningHibernateBundle.<init>(ScanningHibernateBundle.java:22)
    at com.flipkart.accounting.illuminati.IlluminatiApplication$1.<init>(IlluminatiApplication.java:27)
    at com.flipkart.accounting.illuminati.IlluminatiApplication.initialize(IlluminatiApplication.java:27)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:88)
    at com.flipkart.accounting.illuminati.IlluminatiApplication.main(IlluminatiApplication.java:75)
```

I tried bumping the jersey verion as mentioned here:
[Migrate Jersey project to use Java 10 results in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658991/migrate-jersey-project-to-use-java-10-results-in-java-lang-illegalargumentexcept)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it didnt work for me.
Please help me find the issue

Comment: What was good enough for Java 10 in the year 2018 is still too old for Java 17 in 2023. How about going to the *latest* version of Jersey instead of copying an arbitrary version number from the Internet?

Comment: I also faced this problem with the same year. However, I still haven't found a solution to the problem. If you find a solution please share

Comment: @Holger I had the same problem. In the codebase I am working with Jersey 1.x is used. So I want to upgrade Jersey and want to make as small a step as possible to have as less as possible restructurings in the codebase. Finally I want to get to jersey 3. but luckily 2.35 is working with java 17.

Comment: @aminator you can migrate in as many steps as you want, as long as migrate to a combination of compatible software components. Jumping from Java 8 to Java 17, as the OP did, is not what I call a small step, but anyway, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76959419/2711488) already points out where to look for the compatibility. I don’t know whether you looked there or used a different approach to find out that 2.35 works with Java 17, but whatever approach you used, it seems to be better than what the OP did.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the best place to find a Jersey version that supports a certain version of Java / the JDK, is this road map page:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/wiki/Road-Map

As per this page, Jersey 2.35 is the first version to fully support JDK 17.
The currently latest version 2.40 supports JDK 21.