# Migrate Jersey webservices to Java 17 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers

Tags: rest, java-8, jersey, java-17, jersey-client

I'm currently in the process of upgrading my Maven-based Java project from JDK 8 to JDK 17. During this transition, I've encountered a specific error message that's impeding my progress.
Currently i'm using Jersey 2.35.
I am facing the following error:

Here the Exception i got:::

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet \[Servlet_Class\] threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here the Root Cause::

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers
org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:495)
org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.lambda$registerModel$10(ComponentBag.java:454)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.registerModel(ComponentBag.java:446)
org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.register(ComponentBag.java:357)
org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.register(CommonConfig.java:463)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:429)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:306)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:339)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

here the web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Servlet_Class</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <!--<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>webservices.Jersey</param-value>
      </init-param> -->
      <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>webservices.Jersey.Servlet_Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Servlet_Class</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/Jersey/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

here the Servlet_Application.class

```
package webservices.Jersey;

import org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature;  
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class Servlet_Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Servlet_Application() 
    {
        
        packages(true, "webservices.Jersey");
        register(LoggingFeature.class);

        register(Servlet_Class.class);
        
    }
}
```

Please help me find the issue and suggest suitable Jersey library version to be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate Jersey project to use Java 17 results in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589725/migrate-jersey-project-to-use-java-17-results-in-java-lang-illegalargumentexcept)

Comment: You did not show us the stacktrace for the failure of the static initialization of `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers`.  So we can't tell you exactly went wrong.  However the duplink ^^^ tells you what version of Jersey is compatible with Java 17.

Comment: And you should correct the apparent typo in your question's title.

Comment: Hi @StephenC I'm sorry that all info i can provided. There is no more stacktrace for the failure. I'm also use Jersey library as duplink ^^^ which is 2.35.

Comment: Well ... the problem is caused by a static initialization failure in this class: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.x/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/Providers.java.  But without a stacktrace for the resulting exception, I don't think we can narrow the cause down any further.

Comment: so may i know is there anything can i do for now? and which jersey library contain that class

Comment: 1) Yea ... figure out how to get that stacktrace!  Or maybe figure out how to set a breakpoint in the class initialization code and use the debugger to see what it happening. 2) The common-core one ... based on the source code structure.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I simply updated the Jersey library to version 2.41 and the HK2 library to version 2.6.1. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I simply updated the Jersey library to version 2.41 and the HK2 library to version 2.6.1.